# How to get source artifact repository for coordinates in my local .m2 folder

Tags: java, maven

In Maven, it is possible to pull in dependencies from repositories other than Maven central. Since Maven 3.1(?), this source information seems to get stored alongside the actual package in the local `.m2/repository` folder. For example, there is a file in that folder called `org/junit/jupiter/junit-jupiter-api/5.4.0/_remote.repositories` with the following content:

```
#NOTE: This is a Maven Resolver internal implementation file, its format can be changed without prior notice.
#Mon Nov 08 15:59:31 CET 2021
junit-jupiter-api-5.4.0.pom>central=
junit-jupiter-api-5.4.0.jar>central=
junit-jupiter-api-5.4.0-sources.jar>central=
```

In this case, the package was obviously pulled from Maven Central. I found other packages though that had entries like `github`, `gitlab` or even more cryptic keys (with key, I mean everything between `>` and `=`). It seems that this key was the `id` that has been used for the `repository` entry in the original `pom.xml` that depended on said coordinate.

What I am currently trying to understand is how to recover this information or if this is even possible. I would assume that there is a "look-up table" somewhere, which should map the key back to the base URL of the Maven repository... but where would I find it?

Any pointers are appreciated.

Comment: Via the settings.xml it has been possible since Maven 2.X. `In this case, the package was obviously pulled from Maven Central.` how do you come to that conclusion?

Comment: The name `central` seems to suggest that. ;) My `settings.xml` do not contain a single custom repository. It would also be surprising to find that information there, as the settings are the user perspective (e.g., my configured server credentials), not the perspective of internal storage.

Comment: The name you see can be whatever you like. If you don't define to consume from something different than it's ok... if you consume from a repository for example the names says nothing (for example in my files I see `nexus`)...

Answer (score 1):

If you want to see from where dependencies are sourced, you can use the Maven Dependency Plugin's `list-repositories` goal.

https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/list-repositories-mojo.html

Comment: If you are using a repository that will not show where they comming from ... Only where they are consumed from... for example from your repository manager ...

Comment: Thanks Oliver, this is very helpful! I did not find a way to just provide a coordinate "on-the-fly", so I would need a `pom.xml` to "bootstrap" the lookup: add whatever coordinate I am interested in as a dependency to an artificial, otherwise empty `pom.xml`. Even though this `pom.xml` does not contain the originating repo definition(!), the `dependency:list-repositories` goal is able to recover the source. The question remains, where does this plugin get the information from? There is a missing puzzle piece between `pom.xml` and `_remote.repositories`... :>